# How to test malloc failure in C?

Tags: c, gcc, memory, malloc

I wrote some code in `C` and I need to handle the situation that fail to `malloc()` or `realloc()`. I know that if memory allocation failed, it will return `NULL`, and I wrote something as follow：

```
    char *str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    if (str == NULL)
    {
        puts("Malloc Failed.");
        // do something
    }
    // do something else
```

So the problem is, how can I test this part of code?

It is impossible to run out of my memory on my machine by hand. So I want to restrict the biggest memory size it can use.

Can I specify the maximum memory size my program can use when I compile/run it? Or is there any technique to do it?

For your information, I write code in standard `C`, compile it with `gcc`, and run it on Linux environment.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In your test you could replace `malloc` by your own function that `NULL`. Or you could add some `#ifdef MEMORY_TEST str=NULL;#endif` to fake the failure

Comment: @Karl ZHU Replace `malloc()` with your own function that sometimes calls `malloc()` and sometimes return `NULL`.

Comment: allocate big enough chunk, size `~0ull` should be good, as it gives you unsigned long long with every bit set to 1, ie. maximum value.

Comment: Also, on Linux, and also MacOs etc, `man ulimit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a test file that essentially overrides `malloc`.

First, use a macro to redefine `malloc` to a stub function, for example `my_malloc`.  Then include the source file you want to test.  This causes calls to `malloc` to be replaced with `my_malloc` which can return whatever you want.  Then you can call the function to test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define malloc(x) my_malloc(x)

#include "file_to_test.c"

#undef malloc

int m_null;

void *my_malloc(size_t n)
{
    return m_null ? NULL : malloc(n);
}

int main()
{
    // test null case
    m_null = 1;
    function_to_test();
    // test non-null case
    m_null = 0;
    function_to_test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, yet only 1 UV allowed. Hmm, OTOH ....

Answer (score 2):

you can simply give malloc a big number to allocate and it will fail to allocate the size you trying to.